# Label encoding with possible unseen data

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I have a dataframe with multiple columns which need to be label-encoded.
Problem is that the test group may include unseen data (classes) in the future.
I'd like those classes to be labeled as a group of their own so that the code won't crash when I predict new data sets.

I tried using sklearn labelencoder but received.

```
ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'rat'
```

I also need the encoder to be reusable, meaning that I'll be able to encode future datasets with the same values.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Try safelabelencoder from skutils : https://tgsmith61591.github.io/skutil/_modules/skutil/preprocessing/encode.html#SafeLabelEncoder - It fills unseen value as 999999

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same difficulty a multiple times.

My workaround is a bit expensive though

```
le=LabelEncoder()
le.fit(trainDf)

le.classes_=np.array([-99999] + le.classes_.tolist())
testDf[~testDf.isin(le.classes_)]=-99999 #anything that is not used in your dataframe and the same datatype (here int64)

le.transform(testDf)
```

Comment: Still getting error message. Here's the code I used:

for i in cat_feats:
    print(i)
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit_transform(train[i])
    le.classes_ = np.array([np.nan]+ le.classes_.tolist())
    test.loc[~test[i].isin(le.classes_),i] = np.nan
    le.transform(test[i])

Getting 
ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: nan

Comment: My bad, np.nan is not being recognised, tried -99999 now, check edit.

Answer (score 1):

I slightly updated [Sayan Dey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13717851/sayan-dey) idea:

Step 1: label encoding the calsses which exist in the label encoder.
Step 2: fitting the label encoder then setting to -1 all classes in test which are NOT in the encoder.

```
i='browser'
le = LabelEncoder()
train[i] = le.fit_transform(train[i])
#Set classes in test which don't exist in the encoder to -1
test.loc[~test[i].isin(le.classes_),i] = -1    
#Encode classes that exist in the encoder
test.loc[test[i].isin(le.classes_),i] = le.transform(test[i][test[i].isin(le.classes_)])
```

Comment: If -1 is absent in your dataframe then this is fine.

Comment: Correct!
Also need to encode out of encoder classes and only then encode otherwise everything might get -1.
I made the changes to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved with scikit-learn is using the class [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) with parameter `handle_unknown='ignore'`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
encoder.fit(train)

encoder.transform(train)
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather not use onehot encoding